# How can I fix only 1 person being able to pickup items in Minecraft Bed Wars?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm currently making Bed Wars on my Minecraft server.

Right now, only 1 person at a time can pickup items from the generators. How can I fix this?

(More explanation:)
Everyone can pickup items, but just really not at the same time.
I want that if 4 people stand on a generator, they all get the items at the same time. So if 4 items would drop on 4 people, there would be 16 picked up in total. Not just 1 person at the same time.

I'm running paper 1618 1.12.2.